# 1 time of 10 get error json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ','

Tags: json, python-3.x, django

i have this ugly noob func:

```
def run_prog(compile_container, user_input, container_file_path):
    # bash doesnt support single quotes or quotes inside double quotes so @# = '
    time_check_command = '/usr/bin/time -f "@# , @#memory@#:@#%M@# , @#time@#:@#%e@#"'
    result = compile_container.exec_run(
        f"/bin/bash -c 'echo {user_input} | {time_check_command} ./a.out'",
        workdir=container_file_path)[1].decode('utf-8')
    result = '{"result":"' + result + ',}'
    result = result.replace('@#', '"')
    result_dict = json.loads(result)
    if result_dict['time'] == '0.00':
        result_dict['time'] = '<0.01'
    return result_dict
```

Most of time it retrun json like this:

```
{
    "result": "888",
    "memory": "1792",
    "time": "<0.01"
}
```

But one time of 10 or mb 20 it raise an error "error json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ','" and i dont know why. Same input always. Can u please tell what is wrong?

Comment: what can be the `user_input`??

Comment: @shourav user_input is always string for example "5 883" in this case, ./a.out return sum of this nums

Comment: You always write the a.out, if you call the app/method multiple time concurrently the result is unpredictable.

Comment: @Max its always run in different container, where a.out was created, exec_run is doker SDK func

Answer (score 0):

So, i dont really sure whats wrong, but switch from json.loads to ast.literal_eval helped.

```
result_dict = ast.literal_eval(result)
```